# How does a Teckmar 262 boiler control determine the anti-short-cycle minimum boiler run time?

Tags: boiler, heat-pump

I have a ground source heat pump (econar 5T unit) being driven by a Tekmar 262 boiler control.  The heat pump has anti-short-cycling protection built in; if the heat pump demand signal is turned off before some minimum run time, the heat pump lights up an anti-short-cycle warning light, which turns off 90 seconds later.  Unfortunately, the documentation does not say what that minimum run time is.  I have experimentally determined that it is something greater than 10 minutes.

The tekmar 262 manual claims it honors some kind of minimum boiler run time, but no-where in the settings or manual can I find a minimum run time setting.  So how do I get it to honor whatever minimum run-time I want?  Right now it is turning off the boiler (heat pump) signal whenever it loses a hot-water demand signal.

Comment: Have you considered contacting Tekmar to ask them? Might be the simplest, most direct, most accurate way of getting the answer.

Comment: Seemingly it just works when you ask it to do so, thus no minimum run time needed

Comment: @FreeMan  Yes, I've contacted Tekmar and they just sent me exerpts from the installation manual which I already have.  Says nothing useful in terms of the actual time.

Comment: @Ruskes  No, it doesn't "just work".  If told to start too soon, it shuts off permanently in a lock-out condition and has to be powered off for at least a minute before being repowered.

Comment: It appears that the red ASC lockout light turns on whenever the unit is "turned off", i.e. the activation contacts to produce heat are opened.  If no "turn on" signal is received for the next ~90 seconds, the ASC lockout light is turned off and the unit will turn back on (start producing heat) when the activation circuit is closed.

Comment: I'd venture to say that this is _not_ a user adjustable feature. If it were, what would prevent the user from adjusting it to, say 10 seconds, which the manufacturer has determined is way too short a pause? I'd imagine that the manufacturer has determined the shortest, safe minimum run time is and "hard coded" the pump to not run any more frequently.

Comment: @FreeMan  I agree, it's hard coded in the *Heat Pump*.  But heat pump run time is determined by the controller, not the heat pump. The controller is made by a different company.  The controller's notion of minimum run time may be shorter than the heat pump's.  I would like to know what it is, or how it is computed, so I know whether some situation may cause a problem or not.  I have two heat pumps in a 2-stage arrangement, and a recent situation where in -40 weather both pumps were shut off indefinitely with short-cycle errors.

Comment: Understanding that you've been in touch with Tekmar already, maybe contact them and try to get hold of a "help desk" person by complaining that you have a problem (tell them what you said in your last sentence above). You'll get the first level person who won't know anything and will send you back to the manual. If you tell him you've already done those things, you may be able to get them to escalate you to a 2nd level support that gets you closer to the engineers who can actually explain what's going on.